# jQuery Mobile only scroll content, not whole page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll, scrollview

i´m building an app with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap. Now when I got a page and need to scroll, jQuery Mobile scrolls the whole page, and not the content. The scrollbar should be only where the content section is. But it appears that the scrollbar scrolls the whole page. It is on top the fixed header and the fixed footer. Anyone solved this problem?

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using [iScrollView](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) plugin to scroll the content only