# Scroll the content of a certain div in a jQuery-mobile 'page' and not the page itself

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery-mobile for an html based mobile app.

I use jQuery-mobile to horizontally scroll through pages with swipe.

One of my pages has a horizontally long div with some animated content. I need only the content of this div to scroll to the side. But when I swipe over the div, jQuery-mobile scrolls to the next page.

If the user swipes over any other part of the page, this is the desired behavior, but when a swipe occurs on that particular div, I need only the content to scroll.

I tried using [iScrollView](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227907/jquery-mobile-only-scroll-content-not-whole-page) and css overflow as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197605/705972) but in each case, jQuery-mobile scrolls the page.

Is there way to only scroll the content of a certain div in a jQuery-mobile 'page' and not the page itself?

Comment: are you using `swipeleft` / `swiperight`? you can `e.preventDefault()` if `e.target` equals that div.

Comment: thank you @Omar. I tried it and it stopped the page from scrolling. But the div does not scroll either.

Comment: Ok.I figured the div will scroll by adding `overflow: scroll;` to the container.

Comment: i'm glad you got it solved :)

Comment: @Omar, why do not you make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `preventDefault()` or `return false` on swiping on a specific element and its' children.

Identify that element with a `.class`.

```
$(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("class") || $(".class").has(e.target).length) {
    /* true */
    return false;
  } 
  else {
    /* false */
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/kGG33/)**